# Photoshop Question regarding Fill/Stroke

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Recently saw a logo that had an interesting design:

[image]

I really like the mottled color effect within the letters "UC", and was wondering how I would go about doing something similar? I was thinking something with clipping masks, but I'm not sure.
Also, I noticed that the stroke (Border) around the shield is 3 different colors. How would I go about doing that?
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logo, I see those layers (from front to back):

1. black text "HARVARD"
2. black text "UNDERGRADUATE"
3. black text "COUNCIL"
4. black text "19   82"
5. graphic symbol (between 19 82)
6. grey shield with "UC" mask
7. background pattern with (slightly bigger) shield mask

There is no colored border around the shield, it is simply smaller.

As usual, there are many ways to build the same graphic.
This is just one solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be the following:

1- create a background with geometrical shapes which intersect/partially cover each other

2- create the grey layer and add a gradient/shadow

3- write all you want, select the text and cut it off from the grey layer to make the colored layer visible through the letters

4- hide/delete the original text